# php artisan migrate - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As soon, i press Enter 'php artisan migrate' command on ubuntu terminal. Error coming like:- **[PDOException] Could Not Find Driver**

I'm not able to fix this problem as i'm new to it.

Please help me to fix this issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.google.ro/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=[PDOException]+Could+Not+Find+Driver&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=mKbpVYftI4X9UIj7tcgL)

Comment: Do you have seperated php configurations for your CLI? Maybe the modules are not loaded in CLI only

Comment: `php -i | grep php.ini` should return which php.ini file is used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made changes in "Project-Folder-Name/config/database.php". And, it worked. Added 'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DatabaseName'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', //Your sock got from above
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Comment: This isn't the right solutions, because /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock is far from the default configuration and it will break your application on other environments/systems.

Answer (score 1):

Yo should be enable the PDO extension for you Database Manager in you php.ini

```
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll //In my Case the extension enable is for pgsql
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

For enable you should delete the ; char in the line of the extension
restart the server and voila

Comment: Hi Mr Pastor. I was waiting for this answer only. As i searched many answer posted in stack over flow. Everyone asking whether PDO is enabled or not. But, for me ";extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll" is available.. So, it's enabled. Now, what to do next.?

Comment: i've to install php5-sqlite ?

Comment: Well, do you have it? The php-mssql extension.

sudo apt-get install php5-php5-sybase and later  pear install --nodeps MDB2_Driver_mssql

Comment: yeah. i installed this sybase

Comment: do you show me your phpinfo()??. The section PDO only please.

Comment: yeah. I Updated my question with PHP info file. You Can Check it Mr Pastor.

Comment: You only have enable the mysql,pgsql and sqlite drivers. If you recent enable the mssql driver please restart the webserver.

Comment: Ok. I'm restarting it.

Comment: Show me your phpinfo() again.

Comment: Edited My Question. You Can See It Mr Parter

Comment: you still disable the mssql extension for enable edit your php.ini (For enable you should delete the ; char in the line of the extension)  ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

Comment: oh. is it so. Ok let me do.

Comment: Yeah Mr Pastor. I Edited my question with phpinfo( screenshot.) can you please check it..

Comment: Edit your changes into php-cli.ini file please. You still disable the mssql extension

Comment: php-cli.ini file. ?? Where is this file located. Whatever you told me to do changes in php.ini.. i did.. Now, this is new file or what ??

Comment: sorry i mean php.ini in folder /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: I made changes Pastor.

Comment: But, still same result

Comment: please chek this article http://blog.andyhunt.info/2013/11/29/php-mssql-pdo_dblib-freetds-support-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/

Comment: The oficial docshttp://us3.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php say that you should be use http://www.freetds.org/ for enable the extension

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a seperated configuration file (php.ini) for your CLI.

Try to execute `php -i | grep php.ini` in your console. And enable the required modules in that file.

It should return something like this:

```
sander@sander-Laptop:~$ php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

As you can see it uses another php.ini file then what the `phpinfo();` returns

Open that file and enable the required extensions there

so change the lines of the extensions that you require: 
`;extension=extension.so` to `extension=extension.so`

Also a tip: If you use Laravel you can use the Homestead (vagrant, virtualbox) which is an virtual machine complete preinstalled for you laravel application

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead