# Solution To "Could not find driver" & "can't connect to local MYSQL server through socket" - Laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

`Hi All, Since I'm a newbie to laravel. First time coming to LARAVEL. I Faced lots of problem regarding command like` "`php artisan migrate`".

Error Like,

- [PDOException]: Could not find driver
- [PDOException]: Can't Connect to local MYSQL server through socket.

  I was searching the solution like anything. Mr.Bordan Helped Me Lot to find a solution. 2 Days I sat in front of my desktop to find the solution. But, unfortunately I was unable to get the answer. 
  I Asked question Here.
- [Could not connect to local MySQL server with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440938/could-not-connect-to-local-mysql-server-laravel/)
- [php artisan migrate - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400196/php-artisan-migrate-laravel/)
- [bind-address not present in my.cnf file - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437796/bind-address-not-present-in-my-cnf-file-laravel/)

  So,i don't want anyone to search so many answer.. I got answer. I will Share my answer here with you all people here itself.

  Below is my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
 - Find your php.ini file in your system using $ php -i |grep php\.ini command.
   Or, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli
 - Open php.ini file. 
 - And, make sure these lines are present or not.
   a)  extension=mysql.so b) extension=pdo_mysql.so
 - If Yes, remove (;) this before them.
 - If not present, run this command `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`
```

Now, type `php artisan migrate` command. I'm sure you will get error `cant connect to local MYSQL server through socket`

```
Now, 
 - Change bind-address from localhost to 127.0.0.1
 - Run `/opt/lampp/bin/php`. 
 - After running this if you get "unable to load dynamic library", remove `php_mssql.dll extension` (for non-windows)
 - If not getting error, come directly to "Project-Name-Folder/config/database.php" file and add this code 'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Find the complete path of mysql.sock, and add it

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'danishLara'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket'   => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', //Add this line here
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Check this [Setting up Laravel on a Mac php artisan migrate error: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: not working for me